# Dynamically Add Field to Model Keystonejs and Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pug, keystonejs

Seems like a simple task but I don't see anything that shows how to dynamically add a field to a model in keystone.js. For instance, I have an "Animal" model and that animal may belong to an arbitrary number of "Habitats". I would like to be able to go into the Animal models and have a "Assign Habitat" button that would create a new field which would relate the Animal to a Habitat, as many times as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may not have made it into the documentation yet, but what you want is an inline relationship to the Habitats model.

If you define your habitats model as normal, and then your animal model should include something like:

```
Animal.add({
    fieldA: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'Habitat', createInline: true },
});
```

Comment: thanks. That's helpful but I still need to hardcode the number of fields. I took another approach where I generate the fields from a function. `Habitat.add(
            function(_animal){ ...});` Didn't want to paste the whole thing but basically it looks in Animals to determine how many fields to create. This works except that it only generates the number of animals when compiled. If I start the server and add a new animal, it won't be added to Habitats because Habitats is already compiled. Is there a way to re-compile the model whenever the create page is loaded in the admin ui?

Comment: Ah, if you add `many: true` to my example you'll be able to add as many habitats to the animal as you like, just in the one field. Sorry I forgot that in my original answer. On the habitats model you can make it so you can view the relationship from the other side (I.e. view all animals assigned to the habitat you're viewing). Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks. That's super helpful. Ideally though I'd like to populate the Habitats admin UI page with a boolean checkbox for each existing animal. This would basically do the same thing as the relationship dropdown but it might be a bit more readable if it were checkboxes. I wrote a function to do this in my Habitat model but it's only updated with new Animals when the keystone server starts, not each time the admin UI page is loaded, so it doesn't stay up to date. If pulling this off requires a lot of in-depth fiddling with Keystone, I may just go with the relationship dropdown though.

Comment: Okay, yeah that will be much more complicated. We're working on opening up the framework to a plugin architecture so that you can add your own plugins, but that's a while off yet.

You say "I may just go with the relationship dropdown", so I think you've maybe still not got the relationship view working. Have a look at the relationship at the bottom of [this post](http://demo.keystonejs.com/keystone/posts/588f6bf19a39fa040030a79d) on the demo project. You can see the comment relationship. Username `demo@keystonejs.com` password `demo`. You could have it so that gives you the related animals?

Comment: Thank you so much for your support! Really appreciate it. Got the relationship working. If I understand correctly, a schema plugin might be able to take care of populating a certain number of checkboxes right? So in the pre hook in Habitats I could query Animals and create a checkbox for each one? Sorry, I'm pretty new to keystone so I may be totally misunderstanding that. If so, I'll keep it simple and stick with the default relationship setup.

Comment: You can't add new fields using the pre-save hook. 

What you can do is have a `noedit` html field, which you populate pre-save with the list of animals. This is a (perhaps slightly hacky way) or displaying any html you like. You'd then be able to list all the animals. 

However, as far as I know there is still no way to be able to have this html do anything (i.e. the check boxes won't do anything).

Comment: I think you need to work out which way round you want things to work. You can either be able to select certain habitats for the animals when you create an animal, OR select which animals belong to the habitat when you create the habitat. It doesn't work both ways. 

Whichever way you're using, you'll have to use the built-in relationship field with `many: true`, which will give you the dropdown list to choose which items to add. 

Having checkboxes will likely be supported once we implement the plugin architecture, but as I said this is a while off.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so what I ended up doing was setting up keystone restful api and using 3 ajax requests that run on the habitats page.

ajax request #1 – GET the names of all the animals and use jquery to create divs with checkboxes for each one

ajax request #2 – PATCH the habitat item with a string containing the id of each checked animal for that habitat

ajax request #3 – GET the active animals that have previously been selected for the habitat and pre-check their boxes when the page loads

What this does is dynamically create a checkbox for each existing animal on the currently open habitat item page. Checking an animal checkbox associates it with the currently open habitat. That gets saved as a string created for the habitat model.